# XQuery get distinct values after tokenize?

Tags: xquery, tokenize, concatenation, distinct-values

I want to get the distinct countries of all mountains, but sometimes a mountain will be in more than one country as indicated by having multiple country codes in a string like this:

```
<mountain id="mount-Kangchendzonga" country="NEP IND"></mountain>
```

I can get all the distinct strings associated with a country using

```
let $mts := doc("mondial.xml")/mondial//mountain 
let $countries := distinct-values(data($mts/@country))
```

But this isn't quite correct because if I had one mountain with country="NEP IND" and another with country="NEP" these would be recognized as distinct.

```
let $countries := distinct-values(concat(' ', data($mts/@country)))
let $countries := distinct-values(tokenize(data($mts/@country), "\s+"))
```

Is there a way I could first split up a string of a country by white space, and then get the distinct values of these? I have tried using distinct-values on concatenated and tokenized data like I showed above, but both result in errors with the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible way to combine `tokenize()` and `distinct-values()` to get the distinct country names :

```
let $all-countries := 
    for $c in $mts/@country
    return tokenize($c, "\s+")

let $distinct-countries := distinct-values($all-countries)
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester.com demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/c2362244b8e78e928f1a6a7753b2b4d4)</kbd>**

Or in XQuery 3.1, as suggested in comment below :

```
($mts/@country ! tokenize(., '\s+')) => distinct-values()
```

Comment: Or in XQuery 3.1: `($mts/@country ! tokenize(., '\s+')) => distinct-values()`